# Password hashing in a C# Windows app, absent ASP.NET's FormsAuthentication?

Tags: c#, .net, hash, passwords

My Win form app doesn't seem to like FormsAuthentication, I'm totally new to hashing so any help to convert this would be very welcome. Thanks.

```
//Write hash
protected TextBox tbPassword;
protected Literal liHashedPassword;

{
  string strHashedPassword = FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile(tbPassword.Text, "sha1");
  liHashedPassword.Text = "Hashed Password is: " + strHashedPassword;    
}

//read hash
string strUserInputtedHashedPassword = FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile( tbPassword.Text, "sha1");
if(strUserInputtedHashedPassword == GetUsersHashedPasswordUsingUserName(tbUserName.Text))
{
  // sign-in successful
}
else
{
  // sign-in failed
}
```

Comment: Is the goal to have an app that allows users to specify different credentials than the logged in user?  To obtain credentials for use in accessing other services?  I'm not sure what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 23):

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;

public static string EncodePasswordToBase64(string password)
{  byte[] bytes   = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(password);
   byte[] inArray = HashAlgorithm.Create("SHA1").ComputeHash(bytes);
   return Convert.ToBase64String(inArray);
}
```

Comment: Very clean - I tested our two implementations and yours is a bit faster.. 50ms faster on 100,000 iterations, so I'm upvoting it :)

Comment: Bear in mind that SHA1 is (apparently) faster, but would be less secure than SHA256.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA256 for more information

Comment: @JarrodDixon: On the contrary.  For passwords, you want a _slower_ hash.

Answer (score 3):

The FormsAuthentication is defined in the System.Web.Security namespace which is in the System.Web.dll assembly.

Just because you are writing a WinForm app does not stop you from using that namespace or referencing that assembly; they are just not done by default as they would be for a WebForms app.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the hashing for user credentials I suggest you do more than just hashing, you ideally want key stretching as well.

Here is an API to do what you want in a secure fashion:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/pwdtknet/

Comment: I don't see any source code there. Not sure anyone's going to trust their passwords to a .DLL they don't know anything about.

Comment: Source is there in the files area in the folder named "source". Source is provided for exactly the reason you describe. here is a link to the source folder http://sourceforge.net/projects/pwdtknet/files/Source/

Answer (score 1):

I think it should work. All you need to do is reference System.Web.Security in your code (and add it as a reference in your Visual Studio Project).

Answer (score 1):

If you actually have to 'ship' this forms app, maybe adding System.Web.Security is not such a good idea...

If you need an SHA1 hash, there is a very easy to use .net cryptography library with examples on msdn.    The key is to

1. take what you want to encrypt
2. turn it into bytes for whichever encoding(ascii, utf*) you are using
3. Use one of the many hashing schemes builtin to .Net to get the hashed bytes
4. turn those bytes back into a string in the same encoding as in step 2
5. Save the resulting hashed string somewhere for later comparison

---

```
//step 1 and 2
byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(tbPassword.Text,);
byte[] result; 

//step 3
SHA1 sha = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider(); 
result = sha.ComputeHash(data);

//step 4
string storableHashResult = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.ToString(result);

//step 5
    // add your code here
```

Comment: Other than the obvious "it's not meant for WinForms apps", is there a reason why including System.Web.* is not such a good idea?

Comment: Reminds me of a post by Rick Strahl at http://www.west-wind.com/Weblog/posts/617930.aspx

1. It doesn't "feel" right.
2. It forces System.Web into the loaded assebly list of any application consuming the library.
3. It adds 2.5 megs to the memory footprint just for loading it.
4. etc. (out of room)

Answer (score 1):

Could you not use the BitConverter function instead of the "x2" loop?

e.g.

return BitConverter.ToString(hash).Replace("-", "");